# Create Model and Migration only with single command in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I dont want to create Modal migration and controller because of folder structure of controller but what i want create model(with custom directory) with migration so that i can make controller in my custom directory what will be artisan command for this situation ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here is it:

```php
php artisan make:model Models/ProgramEnroll -m
```

it will create a model in my custom directory with migration